# talend rest client: cannot parse json from RESTresponse

Tags: json, rest, talend

I am using talend tRestclient to make a resful call to an api endpoint

the response is as follows

```
{"data":[{"string":"{ \"id\": \"179931\" }","body":null,"statusCode":200}]}
```

the issue is i am now trying to extract the id, but it is in a string, and talend is saying cannot parse json

the fileinputjson is the part thats erroring, its jsonpath query has been set at "$.data[*]" and "$.data[*].string", everything is failing for the above response

how can i get talend to recognize the array in quotes of data.string as json and not a string

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "tExtractJsonField"

You can see the documentation of the component and a little tutorial [here](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide62EN/tExtractJSONFields)

Comment: i have a tExtractJSONField, but its failing because i guess i dont have the correct JSON path, my current setting are JSONPATH without loop , JSONpath query "$.data[*].string" for the resultset above, error is failed to parse json file

Comment: try to put a column id with "id" in the json query in the textractjsonfield

Comment: the extract is working fine, the error is occuring on the tFileInputJSON, i cannot find the proper jsonpath query to read the above array, ive tried "$.data[*]" and "$.data[*].string" along with numerous others

Comment: you json seem weird. I try to query but fail. http://www.jsonquerytool.com/#/JSONPath (maybe the escape caracter ?)